# how to scrolldown in Javascript table with selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a dynemic table which is using javascript. When page loaded only first elements are seeing in source code, so when i try to scraping values from element only first parts coming. Before scraping i need to scroll down in table div then **scrape** values. So how can i scroll down in spesific div for load all data in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use below code to scroll down  :

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('mydiv').scrollIntoView();")
```

or

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
```